Measurement invariance across groups and time
I want to run a multi-group longitudinal model. Based on prior invariance testing, I can assume scalar invariance across groups and time. So is it appropriate to have both the same intercepts across groups and time in my final SEM? I'm confused because I haven't read about this in any other paper so far.

Yes, if that's what the data tell you, then it's fine to have the same parameters both across groups and time (in fact, invariance is highly desirable for the interpretation).
